# How to specify ebs volume type of every ebs while launching an ec2 instance with AMI in boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ami

I am trying to launch an ec2 instance with an ami which has multiple ebs snapshots. How can i launch an instance from the ami, specifying the ebs volume types of every volume.

Comment: Seems you are fresh for the tool of boto, it is long way to go for you.  Spend time on boto documents, then you will know the answer. Maybe change the direction and start working with `terraform`. Its templates are  easier and readable.

Comment: Been using boto since an year and half and have fair command over it, its just that the way i am doing is not sufficing my purpose. Anyways thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `conn.attach_volume (vol.id, inst.id, "/dev/sdx")` after you have launched the instance!